# jQuery Draggable Inadvertently Gets Destroyed on "Out"

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I have the code below mostly working, but when the draggable items is dragged out of the droppable zone, it seems to get destroyed.  I don't see that that is the default functionality in the jQuery docs.  Am I missing something here?

```
$( function() {
    $(".draggable_' . $question_id . '").draggable();
    $(".droppable_' . $question_id . '").droppable({
        activeClass:"ui-state-active",
        accept:".draggable_' . $question_id . '",
        out: function(event,ui) {
            $(this).text(\'Drop selections here\'); //Put the "placeholder" back
        },
        drop: function(event,ui) {
            $(this).text(\'\'); //Clear out the "placeholder"
            $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(this); //Make the draggable snap into the droppable
        }
    });
});
```

Note: This is actually being echoed by PHP.

Comment: Can you add a html code or create a pen in https://codepen.io/

Answer (score 0):

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove() ...
>   https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Do you really need to detach it if you're just changing  it's position?

Comment: The "destroying" occurs when I move the draggable back out from the droppable though using `out:`.  I don't think `.detach()` is part of this.